# IPv6 DHCP and DNS

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, ipv6

Here is the scenario.  I have W2K3 server as our DNS.  I setup IPv6 DHCP6 W2K8 server to allocate PC addresses.  Seems to work OK and does update the DNS automatically with the AAAA entries.

Problem is both IP4 and IP6 entries use the same name.  So for testing when someone only speicifies a PC name it defaults to the IP4 address.  Ping -6 works fine for forcing the IP6 address, but when connecting to a URL by name in IE it uses IP4.

Is there some way to get IP6 addresses to be auto-renamed as the DNS updates?  Something like PCNAME for IP4 and PCNAMEV6 for IP6?  This would make the process of testing IP6 so much simpler for everyone here.

Thanks for any tips or other solutions here.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following (not sure whether that is supported, either): set up a separate zone for the IPv6 names, e.g. v6.example.com, and have the DHCPv6 server write entries to that zone. Then the name would still be PCNAME, but the v6-only name would be accessible as PCNAME.v6.